# How could I write a query to find duplicate values within grouped rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
locations
---------
contract_id INT
order_position INT   # I want to find any bad data in this column
```

I'd like to find any duplicate `order_position`s within a given `contract_id`.

So for example any cases like if two `locations` rows had a `contract_id` of **"24845"** and both had an `order_position` of **"3".**

I'm using MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HAVING clause can show you instances where duplicates exist:

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
GROUP BY contract_id, order_position
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select contract_id, order_position
from locations
group by contract_id, order_position
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT contract_id, order_position, count(*)
FROM locations
GROUP BY contract_id, order_position
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT contract_id, order_position, COUNT(order_position) AS cnt
FROM locations
GROUP BY contract_id, order_position
HAVING cnt > 1;
```

[Why `COUNT(column)` is usually better than `COUNT(*)`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/) (okay, this was just to differentiate my answer :D)